# Scraping "string" code off URL and putting into vector using rvest in R

Tags: r, rvest

I'm new to r and rvest. I got help with this code two days ago which scrapes all player names and it works well. Now I'm trying to add code to function "fetch_current_players" where it also creates a vector of the player codes for that website (taken off the url). Any help would be appreciated as I've spent a day googling, reading, and watching YouTube videos trying to teach myself. Thanks!

```
library(rvest) 
library(purrr) # flatten/map/safely
library(dplyr) # progress bar

fetch_current_players <- function(letter){

  URL <- sprintf("http://www.baseball-reference.com/players/%s/", letter)
  pg <- read_html(URL)

  if (is.null(pg)) return(NULL)
  player_data <- html_nodes(pg, "b a")
  player_code<-html_attr(html_nodes(pg, "b a"), "href") #I'm trying to scrape the URL as well as the player name
  substring(player_code, 12, 20) #Strips the code out of the URL
  html_text(player_data)
  player_code #Not sure how to create vector of all codes from all 27 webpages
}

pb <- progress_estimated(length(letters))
player_list <- flatten_chr(map(letters, function(x) {
  pb$tick()$print()
  fetch_current_players(x)
}))
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to keep this kind of thing simple and readable, nothing wrong with a for loop. This code returns the names and codes in a simple data frame.

```
library(rvest) 
library(purrr) # flatten/map/safely
library(dplyr) # progress bar

fetch_current_players <- function(letter){
  URL <- sprintf("http://www.baseball-reference.com/players/%s/", letter)
  pg <- read_html(URL)

  if (is.null(pg)) return(NULL)
  player_data <- html_nodes(pg, "b a")
  player_code<-html_attr(html_nodes(pg, "b a"), "href") #I'm trying to scrape the URL as well as the player name
  player_code <- substring(player_code, 12, 20) #Strips the code out of the URL
  player_names <- html_text(player_data)
  return(data.frame(code=player_code,name=player_names))
}

pb <- progress_estimated(length(letters))

for (x in letters) {
  pb$tick()$print()
  if(exists("player_list"))
     {player_list <- rbind(player_list,fetch_current_players(x))
  } else player_list <- fetch_current_players(x)    
}
```